# How to organize production and dev code using git

Tags: git, development-environment, production

Sorry new to git and hence might be basic question.

We have development git repository which is shared among 5-6 developers. We are now planning to move to production. How do I maintain production version separately with access only to 1-2 people. We will be having multiple releases.

One option I have is create new production repository and move the new releases to production. But does not sound effecient. Is there better way to manage it using git?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend release branches, that way you should be able to easily backport fixes with cherry-pick.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the tool [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) to organize your project.

gitolite acts like a very thin git server but with great [authorisation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/concepts.html#auth) support.

I would at first seperate your project into two different branches, namely `develop` and `release` and configure those branches on the gitlote repository.

Later you can create [access rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#rules) to decide what developer is able to push/pull to and from `release`.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to use gitlab. There you can maintain pull requests, just like on github.

You can protect your production branch and only the 1-2 people have the right to merge into this branch. This is achieved thru a role based user system. Only repository Masters can merge into protected branches.